# HTML drop-down change size when shorter option selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have this bit of HTML:

```html
<select name="tables" id="tables">
        <option value="random">Random</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

My problem is that "Random" is has a lot more characters than "1", "2",or "3". When I select, lets say, "2", the box is still the same size as "Random" (try it above). Can I make the size automatically change as the input changes? Even if the number goes to 135?
I'm not new to JavaScript either, so if there is a way to achieve it using JS, I'd be grateful!

Comment: can you try something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/xn538woz/

Comment: @NidhinPrathap Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! Could you make an answer for that to make it easier for others to see it?

Comment: sure will do...

Comment: Please upvote if you found it helfpul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hidden view to store the selected item and get the width corresponding to it and then set the width to your selected view. Check the below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#resizing_select').change(function(){
    $("#width_tmp_option").html($('#resizing_select option:selected').text());
    $(this).width($("#width_tmp_select").width());  
 });
});
```

```css
#resizing_select {
 width: 80px;
} 
 
#width_tmp_select{
 display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="resizing_select">
 <option>random</option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<select id="width_tmp_select">
 <option id="width_tmp_option"></option>
</select>
```